# Kernel hang on resume from suspend on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, 22.04, amd-ryzen, resume

My system will take about a minute to resume from suspend, during which it is unresponsive to input. I get a blank screen (no backlight) until the login screen is displayed, at which point everything functions as normal. The keyboard backlight key does work in this state (expected), but the caps lock indicator LED does not toggle on until the login screen is displayed.

Here are the `journalctl` logs from `kernel`, `systemd-logind` and `systemd-sleep` during the process of suspending and resuming the system immediately:

```
reuben@reuben-Inspiron-14-5425:~$ journalctl -f | grep -E 'kernel|systemd-(logind|sleep)'
Jun 05 01:49:12 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 systemd-logind[748]: Power key pressed.
Jun 05 01:49:12 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun 05 01:49:12 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun 05 01:49:12 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: Lockdown: systemd-logind: hibernation is restricted; see man kernel_lockdown.7
Jun 05 01:49:12 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: wlp3s0: deauthenticating from 00:31:92:fb:37:fb by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Jun 05 01:49:13 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 systemd-sleep[4885]: Entering sleep state 'suspend'...
Jun 05 01:49:13 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.377 seconds
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.202 seconds) done.
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: can't derive routing for PCI INT A
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: pci 0000:00:00.2: PCI INT A: no GSI
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: [drm] PCIE GART of 1024M enabled.
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: [drm] PTB located at 0x000000F400900000
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resuming...
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: dpm has been disabled
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: SMU is resumed successfully!
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: [drm] DMUB hardware initialized: version=0x0101001F
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: [drm] VCN decode and encode initialized successfully(under DPG Mode).
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: [drm] JPEG decode initialized successfully.
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring gfx uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 0
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.0 uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 0
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 0
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.0 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 0
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.0 uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 0
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: ata1: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: ata2: SATA link down (SStatus 0 SControl 300)
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: I/O 91 QID 5 timeout, aborting
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: I/O 953 QID 16 timeout, aborting
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: I/O 954 QID 16 timeout, aborting
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: I/O 955 QID 16 timeout, aborting
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: I/O 956 QID 16 timeout, aborting
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: I/O 28 QID 0 timeout, reset controller
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: Abort status: 0x371
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: PM: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_resume+0x0/0xf0 returns -16
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme 0000:02:00.0: PM: failed to resume async: error -16
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Jun 05 01:50:26 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: nvme nvme0: 16/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Jun 05 01:50:27 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 systemd-sleep[4885]: System returned from sleep state.
Jun 05 01:50:27 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 kernel: PM: suspend exit
Jun 05 01:50:27 reuben-Inspiron-14-5425 systemd-logind[748]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
```

**Things I have tried**

- Installing latest updates through Software Updater and `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`
- Adding `amd_iommu=off` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`, followed by `sudo update-grub`
- Various other `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` tweaks

Any idea what the problem might be? I've read in a few places [[1]](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=AMD-s2idle-Check-FW) [[2]](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1343977/sleep-issue-on-ubuntu-21-04-cpu-amd-5700u) that Ryzen 5000 series CPUs have problems with sleep on Linux. I feel like the next logical step might be to upgrade/downgrade to a different kernel version, but I'm not sure what I should be looking for when picking a specific version, rather than aimlessly guessing which to install (perhaps changelog keywords such as "AMD" and "ACPI"?).

Any help would be much appreciated. :)

---

**System info**

- Model: Dell Inspiron 14 5425
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 5825U
- RAM: 24GB DDR4 3200MHz (1x 8GB, 1x 16GB)
- Ubuntu version: 22.04 LTS
- Kernel version: `5.15.0-35-generic`

**Additional info**

- Dual-boot Ubuntu/Windows 11 from single 1TB NVMe SSD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the extremely late reply, but I have the same laptop as you and found a fix for the issue. Just set the kernel boot parameter `pcie_aspm=off` in /etc/default/grub and then update grub. There's some more info about this parameter [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/power_management_guide/aspm). Hope this helps!

Comment: That worked like a charm - thank you so much! The docs you linked suggest that there must be some component of the laptop that does not support ASPM, which is why I was seeing that hang on wake from suspend (although I never had `pcie_aspm=force` set). Maybe this will get fixed in some firmware/BIOS update from Dell in the future... Have you noticed any notable difference in power consumption/battery usage with `pcie_aspm=off`?

Comment: @Reuben Is there any side-effect of this?

Comment: This also worked on a Asus Vivobook Ryzen 5800hs on integrated graphics, ubuntu 20, kernel 5.15.0-76-generic. Without this  change, it used to take exact 60 seconds for the nvme0 timeout to happen.

Comment: @Kapil I've noticed slightly degraded battery life when both active and in sleep, but I sort of expected that. Otherwise, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

1-switch to 5.18 kernel,stops kernel panic.

2-Sleep is not fixed in 5.18 kernel, try not to use sleep or hibernate, use only lock.

3-There might be some fix in 5.19 kernel,not sure about sleep

4-use "**sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate**"
To hide sleep and hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

This might be worth a shot:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/706594/dell-inspiron-laptop-cannot-wake-from-sleep-in-linux

They suggest abandoning sleep, and using hibernate instead.